# Relations to relation neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher

Maybe it is a long shot but worth trying...
I have the following relation **User1-[:MATCHED]-User2**, I want to allow other users to give feedback (Like) on that relation, I am guessing that the obvious answer is to define new node from type **Match** which will be created for every two matched users and then relate to that node with LIKE relation from each user who liked the match.
I am trying to think about other way to model that in the graph without the overhead of creating new node for each match...

Can a relation relate to other nodes except the start/end nodes?

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I think your idea with creating a new node is probably the best way. You can't relate to more than the start/end nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j does not support hypergraphs or relationships to relationships. Modelling your MATCHED relationship with a node is probably the way to go.

An alternative is to reference the relationship id from another node:

```
User1-[MATCHED]->User2 (where MATCHED has the id xyz)
User3-[LIKES]->Relationship(relId = xyz)
```

The "Relationship" node would contain the id of the MATCHED relationship as a property. This relId property would need to be indexed to find all LIKES of a given MATCHED relationship.

This solution is not well suited for traversals though.